# Value at address disappearing

Tags: c, string

I am writing a program and have the following loop:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    if (c == '\n'){
        char newword[strlen(word) + 1];
        strcpy(newword, word);
        words[i].key = newword;
        memset(word, '\0', MAXLENGTH);          
        i++;
        j = 0;
    } else {
        word[j++] = c;
    }
}
```

Where `words` is an array of structures:

```
struct kvp{
    char *key;
    int line;
};
```

and `word` is a big array (of size `MAXLENGTH`), the first few values of which constitute a string.

The problem rests with `words[i].key`.  Within the if statement, printing it (after setting it to `newword`) will return the correct value, namely, an minimally-sized string that is the same as the word that was entered.  Once the if statement is exited and we're back in the outer body of the while loop, however, it changes to something completely random, i.e. `?HBk?`.

There are three things I suspect could be happening:

- `strcpy` doesn't act the way I think it does
- `newword` is a local variable and that somehow affects things (doesn't sound right)
- I don't properly understand pointers or structures yet (entirely possible, I've just started learning C)

What is going on?

Comment: "doesn't sound right" -- Interesting that you would think that ... your experience is probably with garbage-collected languages. But in C, a variable's scope delimits its lifetime, and using it outside that scope is undefined behavior.

Comment: Definitely good to know, thanks!  And yeah, my experience has been with Java, JavaScript, Ruby, and PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare `newword` in the `if` block, it goes out of scope after that block exits. If you want it to persist, you'll need to either allocate memory in an outer scope, or allocate the string on the heap with `malloc`.

```
if (c == '\n')
{
    // newword will persist beyond this block:
    char *newword = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(newword, word);
    words[i].key = newword;
```

Note that now you'll need to call `free` on this alloc'd block, or create a memory leak. At some later point you'll need to call `free(words[i].key)`.

Martin's suggestion of using [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) is a good one, it `strdup` is available: it will do the alloc for you - but you'll still need to `free` later.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  I wish K&R covered malloc/free better, since I've seen it all over the internet.

Answer (score 2):

newword is being stored on the stack, so it will go out of scope each time the while loop executes.

You need to dynamically allocate memory for it.  I'd suggest replacing

```
char newword[strlen(word) + 1];
strcpy(newword, word);
```

with:

```
char * newword = strdup(word);
```

This will allocate the memory and copy the contents across.  Be aware, you should clean up that memory later with free(), otherwise you'll have a memory leak.